# Exposing Azure Table Storage via WCF Data Service missing OData functions

Tags: c#, azure, wcf-data-services, odata, azure-table-storage

I have a WCF Data Service exposing an Azure table.
This work for CRUD operations and filtering but I am unable to use OData functions like `$top=1`.

I also get errors when trying to use the `IncludeTotalCount()` on the `DataServiceQuery`

The `WcfDataService1.svc.cs`:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<MenuDataServiceContext>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
}
```

The `MenuDataServiceContext`:

```
public class MenuDataServiceContext : IUpdatable
{
    private readonly AzureTableContext tableContext = new AzureTableContext();

    public IQueryable<MenuItemRow> Menu
    {
        get
        {
            var retval = this.tableContext.CreateQuery<MenuItemRow>("Menu").AsTableServiceQuery();
            return retval;
        }
    }

    public void AddReferenceToCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeAdded)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ClearChanges()
    {
        return;
    }

    public object CreateResource(string containerName, string fullTypeName)
    {
        var entity = new MenuItemRow();
        // Add the entity to table context.
        this.tableContext.AddObject(containerName, entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public void DeleteResource(object targetResource)
    {
        var person = targetResource as MenuItemRow;
        if (person == null)
        {
            throw new DataServiceException(400, "Invalid object. Object must be a Person");
        }
        this.tableContext.DeleteObject(person);
        this.tableContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public object GetResource(IQueryable query, string fullTypeName)
    {
        var tableQuery = query as IQueryable<MenuItemRow>;
        if (tableQuery == null)
        {
            throw new DataServiceException(400, "Invalid query.");
        }
        return tableQuery.First();
    }

    public object GetValue(object targetResource, string propertyName)
    {
        var person = (MenuItemRow)targetResource;
        return typeof(MenuItemRow).GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(person);
    }

    public void RemoveReferenceFromCollection(object targetResource, string propertyName, object resourceToBeRemoved)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ResetResource(object resource)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ResolveResource(object resource)
    {
        return resource;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        this.tableContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SetReference(object targetResource, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetValue(object targetResource, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        // The Partition/RowKey should not be modified.
        if (propertyValue != null && propertyName != "PartitionKey" && propertyName != "RowKey")
        {
            var person = (MenuItemRow)targetResource;
            typeof(MenuItemRow).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(person, propertyValue, null);
            this.tableContext.UpdateObject(person);
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like the `MenuDataServiceContext` should implement something other than `IUpdatable` to get the extra functionality.

There are no exceptions throw in the service when debuging but when using the `$top=1` command from the browser, there is a `NotImplemented` exception.

Answer (score 0):

After using wireshark I discovered the call to the table storage service was `$orberby=partitionkey,rowkey&$top=1`.

As azure table storage does not support ordering, I was getting the `NotImplemented` exception.

The now the question is why the WCF Data Service is putting the `orderby` on when doing a take.